# Funq usage in ServiceStack

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack, funq

- How can I access `Container` instance out of controller?
- I have to use `Container.Resolve` in my class but how can I access `Container` instance?
- Is it singleton?
- Can I use `new Container()` or is there any chain like `Funq.StaticContainer`?

Thanks to Mythz [for gist hint](https://gist.github.com/2844693), a) or b) or c).

I will use Mythz's solution, it is accepted by me but there are concerns for it's pattern (`ServiceLocator` Pattern), you can [check here for extra info](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139209/does-funq-ioc-container-support-property-injection

Approach is ok for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to statically reference your AppHost instance. You can resolve a dependency via the [IAppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/IAppHost.cs) instance with:

```
HostContext.TryResolve<T>();
HostContext.Resolve<T>();
HostContext.AppHost.TryResolve<T>();
```

If for some reason you need to access the concrete `Funq.Container`, you can access it via the singleton:

```
ServiceStackHost.Instance.Container
```

Whilst inside a Service, Razor View Page, etc you can use:

```
base.TryResolve<T>();
```

Comment: There is no Resolve<T> method on IAppHost I used TryResolve<T> (comes from IResolver)

Comment: Thanks updated answer. TryResolve returns null for missing dependencies where Resolve would throw a ResolutionException