# Funq scope in ServiceStack (Best Practice)

Tags: servicestack, funq

In my Web application I use a standard mechanism for resolving dependencies into a AppHost.cs

`public virtual void Configure(Container container){ }`

In this method, I register all dependencies.

How can I access Container instance out of controller?

I find an answer: [Funq usage in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837445/funq-usage-in-servicestack)

But Is it the best practice?
What about multi-threading? Isn't it(AppHostBase.Instance.Container) a blocking resource?

Comment: Funq is thread-safe because it's registered in a single application thread in `Configure()` and immutable there after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would stick with the answers found in [Funq usage in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837445/funq-usage-in-servicestack)

It is best to avoid multi-threading solutions in asp.net applications if you can avoid it. Resolving references via funq will be very fast. Funq was chosen for [ServiceStack because of its outstanding performance.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container)

If you do need to use multi-threading then you should be managing your locks **inside** the actual dependencies instead of around the dependency resolutions.