# servicestack serverevents triggered by eventhandler/action

Tags: c#, events, interface, servicestack, eventhandler

Context:
I am using the ServiceStack Framework (4.0.42) for my application. It is selfhosted and runs as a windows service. The main purpose is to give some devices the ability to communicate via web services (RESTful and ServerEvent).

For this I created a common interface for all types of devices which look like this (simplified):

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string GetName();        
    bool IsConnected(string id);
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> RaiseSomeEvent;
}
```

This interface is implemented in DLL’s one for each type of device.

My problem is that I can’t figure out how to forward the RaiseSomeEvent to notify a subscriber to ServerEvents. 
I tried many different implementations, none of them worked. Most, it ended up, that at runtime, when the DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent is called, the ServerEvents instance is null.

I am running out of ideas now.

Here is the actual (simplified) Version:

```
public class ServiceInterface : Service
{
    public IDevice DeviceAdapter { get; set; }         
    public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public ServiceInterface(IDevice deviceAdapter)
    {
        DeviceAdapter = deviceAdapter;
        DeviceAdapter.RaiseSomeEvent += DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent;       
    }

    public void DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerEvents.NotifyAll("Something happend!");            
    }
```

and here the AppHost Class:

```
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public IDevice DeviceAdapter;

    public AppHost()
        : base("grob.MachineConnector.Service", typeof(ServiceInterface).Assembly)
    { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {            
        this.Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature());

        switch (UsedAdapter)
        {
            case enAdapterTyp.DeviceTyp1:
                DeviceAdapter = new DeviceTyp1();
                break;
            case enAdapterTyp.DeviceTyp2:
                DeviceAdapter = new DeviceTyp2();

                break;
            default:
                throw new AdapterTypException("Wrong or no Adaptertyp is configured:" + UsedAdapter.ToString());
        }            
        container.Register(new ServiceInterface(DeviceAdapter));                       
    }
```

Maybe it lies somewhere in the Funq. I am not sure what happening exactly with the DI, IoC, Autowiring stuff. I tried to write my own Plugin for the framework. I have no idea how to get the a valid instance of IServerEvents when a Event rises from my Device. 
Maybe I did some general design faults. For OOP and C# I am at beginner level.

Any hints are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Dependencies are only available within the lifetime of a request, beyond that the Service and its dependencies are released/disposed. It's not clear from the event that it's only raised during the Request:

```
DeviceAdapter.RaiseSomeEvent += DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent;
```

You should also never register a Service as they're automatically registered and autowired by ServiceStack:

```
 //Don't register Services
 //container.Register(new ServiceInterface(DeviceAdapter));
```

Otherwise `IServerEvents` is just a normal Singleton dependency that's registered when the [ServerEventsFeature Plugin is loaded](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/109ad2a8853dcc569c5c6a9f52873e550dfd0ca1/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L64).

Normally you'd just access it like any other dependency, where you'd just resolve it in the dependency that needs it, i.e:

```
container.Register<IDevice>(c => new DeviceTyp1 { 
    ServerEvents = c.Resolve<IServerEvents>()
});
```

Which will automatically inject the resolved `IDevice` into the Service dependencies:

```
public class ServiceInterface : Service
{
    public IDevice DeviceAdapter { get; set; }         

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        //DeviceAdapter also has access to IServerEvents
        DeviceAdapter.Exec(request); 
    }
}
```

But if this event is not in reaction to a Service request then the event shouldn't be tied to a Service, i.e. you could just have the handler in the AppHost:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{            
    DeviceAdapter.RaiseSomeEvent += DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent;       
}

public void DeviceAdapter_RaiseSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var serverEvents = Container.Resolve<IServerEvents>();
    serverEvents.NotifyAll("cmd.Handler", "Something happend!");            
}
```

Please also see the [documentation on Selectors](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client#selectors) so you know which selector the message should be sent with.

See this answer on different ways you can [resolve IOC dependencies from outside of ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840303/85785) may also be helpful.

Comment: hello mythz thanks for you help. your explanaitions was very illustrative.

Comment: in your sample there is a > missing, at this line "var serverEvents = Container.Resolve<IServerEvents();"